Can you do an arrayformula when using index match?
I have the following index match formula in this sheet.
Project Tracking Tab, column B
=IFERROR(INDEX('Project List'!A4:B,MATCH(A2,'Project List'!A4:A,0),MATCH('Project List'!B4,'Project List'!A4:B4,0)),"")

What it does, is it looks at my Project List Tab and pulls information into the Project tracking tab about that project using the Project ID number.
I am also using it on the Staff Effort tab, column B
=IFERROR(INDEX('Project List'!A2:B,MATCH(A8,'Project List'!A2:A192,0),MATCH('Project List'!B2,'Project List'!A2:B2,0)),"")

I am doing it this way instead of ='Project List'!B2 to avoid data issues if someone sorts one of the sheets.

Instead of me having to copy down the formula every time I enter a new Project ID number, I would like these formulas to copy down automatically.
I am using arrayformula for the Project ID, not certain is this can be used for index match formulas.
Note: I do not want to use vlookup because this sheet is evolving and I will be adding columns and making changes.  Index Match allows me to make changes without having to adjust the formula.

I changed my answer to use column references instead of column index numbers so you can insert and delete columns in the lookup sheets and the formulas will adjust similarly to how you are using a reference to the column name in your MATCH formulas..

Formula in 'Project Tracking'

Clear Column B then put the formula in B1

={"Project Name/Project Folder Link"; 
   INDEX(IFNA(
     VLOOKUP(A2:A, 'Project List'!A2:B, 
       COLUMN('Project List'!B2),0)))}

IFNA  INDEX  VLOOKUP
Formula in 'Staff Effort'

Clear B7:C then put the formula in B7
It returns Columns 2 and 14 of 'Project Tracking' if the Project ID matches

={"Project Name/Project Folder Link","Status"; 
   INDEX(IFNA(
     VLOOKUP(A8:A, 'Project Tracking'!A2:N,
      {COLUMN('Project Tracking'!B2),COLUMN('Project Tracking'!N2)},0)))}

